# Undefined reference to `g_Templates'

Tags: linker, mingw, directshow, asio

I am trying to compile ASIO with MinGW for my application, but I keep running into undefined reference to `'g_Templates'`, `'g_cTemplates'`, and `'vtable for AsioDriver'`. I am linking with `-lole32 -luuid`. What additional libraries do I need to compile this?

Google found that this is a DirectShow filter, but MinGW should be able to compile against DirectShow.

Comment: I pinpointed the problem to missing "strmbase.lib", which in MinGW should be "libstrmbase.a". But it is not present in MinGW lib directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by downloading Windows SDK and compiled the DirectShow base classes myself into strmbase.lib.